# What can a person not categorize in the process of his knowledge acquisition?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, properties, experience, categorization

When a subject learns about the world and gets experience as a result, he builds his own mental representations - thereby essentially differentiating the world (that is, dividing it into abstract categories). What can a person not differentiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be considered on different levels:

- Personal: The blind  spots are what a person cannot see, and therefore is unable to discriminate.
- At presence: At each time there are general open questions. Examples
  of open questions in today’s science: Dark energy, the origin of the
  universe, how to reconciliate objective determinism and subjective
  free will.
- In general:  Similarly like a dog cannot understand calculus or the
  problem of free will, I expect also the human species to have their
  mental limits. But it’s in the nature of things that we do not know
  these limits – like every person does not know its own blind spots.

In the 19th century the scientist Dubois-Reymond gave a speech: [The Limits of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoramus_et_ignorabimus). He coined the difference between questions of type "ignoramus, i.e. currently we do not know" and of type "ignorabimus, i.e. we will never know". Dubois-Reymond named several examples.

Answer (score 1):

**Your question is self-defeating.** If a person can conceive the idea, then they can conceive the language to represent it; if they cannot conceive the idea, then they cannot conceive the language to represent it. Therefore, your question is really:

> Use conceived language to describe that which cannot be conceived.

**This must necessarily fail.** Therefore, your question is essentially in the form of a [koan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koan). From WP:

> The popular western understanding sees kōan as referring to an unanswerable question or a meaningless or absurd statement. However, in Zen practice, a kōan is not meaningless, and not a riddle or a puzzle. Teachers do expect students to present an appropriate response when asked about a kōan.

**When one crafts categories, one is using cognitive processes to attribute properties to things, and then listing things as members of sets or [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory).** In the classical method, this is done by definitions of [necessity and sufficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency). As long as you have the ability to list a set of properties, you can create a category, even if they don't physically exist. Unicorns, kelpies, and square circles all have properties, for instance.

But you have created a category of things called things that have no properties and cannot be differentiated. **This is a contradiction because we decide what things are *according* to their properties. Therefore, 'undifferentiated thing' is a fiction in the same way a square circle is.**